# How to retrieve a URL from a PHTML: <?php urlsite(); ?>

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I'm helping a client to change a Paypal bouton link on her website. When I go into the page, the only piece of code I see is this one:

```
<div class="ccenter info2"><a href="<?php urlsite(); ?>makePayment" class="btn btn-large">Payer</a></div>
```

The files on her website are mostly PHTML extension. What I'd like to do is to know where the "php urlsite" is leading to? When I click on the website, it directs toward the Paypal payment but no URL is being called between the (). Is there a way to find out?

I've also looked on www.php.net to find a solution, Google and here as well and I can't seem to find one. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.: Is Magento the only thing to be using PHTML? Client is not aware if Magento has been used for her website or not.

Comment: You may get the information as to 'where the link is taking you to' from the page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phtml is the extension for Zend Framework template files. It does not necessarily mean they are using Magento, as many projects use ZF.

When you call `<?php urlsite(); ?>` it's likely returning the base URL for the site. You would need to find the function within the controller to find out what it does.